# Openpyxl error: Keyerror(worksheet <0> does not exist )

Tags: python, openpyxl

I know this kind of question has been asked and accepted answer has been given. But the solution does not work for me. So I am asking this question separately.

I have 2 excel files in My Documents directory:

- pythonread.xlsx
- pythonread.xls

Both have same numeric data. Both files were created by me to check if I can run simple openpyxl based script or not.
Here is the script:-

```
from xlrd import open_workbook 
from openpyxl import Workbook 
wb = open_workbook('C:\\Users\\patilpb\\Documents\\pythonread.xls')
wb1 = Workbook('C:\\Users\\patilpb\\Documents\\pythonread.xlsx')
for s in wb.sheets():
     print 'Sheet:',s.name
     values = []
     for row in range(s.nrows):
      col_value = []
      for col in range(s.ncols):
            value  = (s.cell(row,col).value)
            try : value = str(int(value))
            except : pass
            col_value.append(value)
      values.append(col_value)
#print values
wb1_1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
wb1_2 = wb1['Sheet2'] 
cell_range = wb1_1['B3':'B100']
print cell_range.value
```

On running the script (Anaconda prompt currently but also ran on Winpython prompt), I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
wb1_1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
File "C:\~path~\workbook.py", line 173, in get_sheet_by_name
   return self[name]
File "C:\~path~\workbook.py", line 192 in __getitem__ 
   raise KeyError("Worksheet (0) does not exist." .format(key))
KeyError: 'Worksheet Sheet1 does not exist.'
```

Before that, commands for xlrd importing xls files are executed fine. And it prints default sheets' names (Sheet1, 2 & 3). Even reads (if I want) prints the data. But same does not happen with .xlsx file. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the `wb1.get_sheet_names()` return?

Comment: Did you tried load_workbook method? https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file

Comment: FWIW xlrd can read XSLX files just fine.

Comment: @alecxe wb1.get_sheet_names() does not give any output.

Comment: @ Charlie Clark I didn't know that. I will try to use xlrd for .xlsx too. But then why openpyxl? Anyway since issue remains with what is standard instructions for openpyxl, I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @alpert I will try load workbook and let know if it works for me.

Comment: @alpert Thank you, load_workbook method works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **load_workbook** method which specified in official documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file